# File doesn't compile in VS code, But works fine in Overleaf

Tags: xetex, overleaf, vscode, latex-workshop

I've found a template that works fine in Overleaf (using XeLaTeX), and I decided to download all the files and use it in VS code. The issue is that when I tried to compile the file using Recipe:latexmk (exlatex) but it doesn't work at all! I've tried to figure out why but no luck.

The Overleaf template:
https://www.overleaf.com/read/cbqwwttzmfkk

**Edit: Adding more information to provide support**

I've already installed MikTeX, and the log file is as shown in the link below:
https://github.com/TechnocracyArabic/starmap/blob/main/Log%20File

with error as the image below shows:
[image]

I'm using Windows 10, with LaTeX Workshop v9.7.0, with all packages updated to the latest version.

Thank You for your help.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Your question lacks some details, for example: did you install locally a TeX distribution like TeXLive or MikTeX?

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to this forum and I don't know what details to add. But yes, I did install MikTeX

Comment: show what code you ran and what error (from the log file) you got. no one can debug "it doesn't work at all!"

Comment: I've updated the question and provided all the information needed (I hope so).
Thank you for your patient

Comment: it is better to show errors as a text block not an image, and you have still not shown your code, but one error says you have not use `\usepackge{bidi}` so use that (as you seem to be using polyglossia) your other errors are `\swdefault` not defined it should be defined by latex (2020/02/02 release) so you presumaby have an old latex installation or (for some reason??) have  used `latexrelease` to rollback latex and remove newer features